# i tried to connect planetscale database but not possible

Tags: database, planetscale

below is my code

`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

db_connection_string = "mysql+pymysql://dvgrfhodw7c31y4ss9j5:dvgrfhodw7c31y4ss9j5@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/aws.connect.psdb.cloud?charset=utf8mb4"

engine = create_engine(
    db_connection_string,
    connect_args= {
        "ssl": {
            "ssl_ca": "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"
        }
    }
)

with engine.connect(db_connection_string) as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("select * from jobs"))
    print(result.all())
```

`

the error am getting is this
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'dvgrfhodw7c31y4ss9j5'")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

i want to connect to planet scale database but getting access denied

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `db_connection_string` from the `connect()` call. Usually its just `engine.connect()`. You already added the db_connection_string as an argument for the engine in the lines above. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you typed wrong Username when connecting to DataGrip